# I want to create table dynamically using plsql here is a code but its not working it shows this error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_TABLE_CREATE(D_NAME in VARCHAR2, D_TABLE_SPECS in VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE' || D_NAME || '(' || D_TABLE_SPECS || ')' ;
```

END;

[image]

Comment: Change `'CREATE TABLE'` to `'CREATE TABLE '` (add a space between `TABLE` and the string literal terminator `'`).

Comment: Please, describe your original problem you want to solve. Dynamic table **creation** is not what should be performed in general taksk, because table is reusable object and should be created once and forever.

Comment: Brother thanks i have correct my mistake i was not giving space between table and string literal now its working thanks all of you

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL is ... well, option you should use if you must. I'd suggest you not to dynamically create tables.

If you must, then it is a good habit to compose the statement first (into a local variable) and **display** its contents so that you could check whether it is OK:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_TABLE_CREATE (D_NAME         IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                                    D_TABLE_SPECS  IN VARCHAR2)
  3  IS
  4     l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
  5  BEGIN
  6     l_str := 'CREATE TABLE' || D_NAME || '(' || D_TABLE_SPECS || ')';
  7
  8     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
  9  --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> EXEC dynamic_table_create('super_man', 'id number');
CREATE TABLEsuper_man(id number)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As you can see, your code is trying to run this statement:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLEsuper_man(id number)
  2  /
CREATE TABLEsuper_man(id number)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command


SQL>
```

There's a **space missing** between `table` and table name. So, fix it, and then uncomment `execute immediate`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_TABLE_CREATE (D_NAME         IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                                    D_TABLE_SPECS  IN VARCHAR2)
  3  IS
  4     l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
  5  BEGIN
  6     l_str := 'CREATE TABLE ' || D_NAME || '(' || D_TABLE_SPECS || ')';
  7     --                    ^
  8     --           add space here
  9     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
 10
 11     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 12  END;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> EXEC dynamic_table_create('super_man', 'id number');
CREATE TABLE super_man(id number)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM super_man;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Now it works.

Comment: Yes thanks its working fine i  was not giving space btween table and side literal now its working